# Getting latest tasks from Celery and display them using Django

Tags: django, sqlite, celery, django-celery

I have a Django 1.5.1 webapp using Celery 3.0.23 with RabbitMQ 3.1.5. and sqlite3.
I can submit jobs using a simple `result = status.tasks.mymethod.delay(parameter)`, all tasks executes correctly:

```
[2013-09-30 17:04:11,369: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: status.tasks.prova[a22bf0b9-0d5b-4ce5-967a-750f679f40be]
[2013-09-30 17:04:11,566: INFO/MainProcess] Task status.tasks.mymethod[a22bf0b9-0d5b-4ce5-967a-750f679f40be] succeeded in 0.194540023804s: u'Done'
```

I want to display in a page the latest 10 jobs submitted and their status. Is there a way in Django to get such objects? I see a couple of tables in the database (`celery_taskmeta` and `celery_taskmeta_2ff6b945`) and tried some [accesses to the objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824172/find-out-whether-celery-task-exists) but Django always displays a `AttributeError` page.
What is the correct way to access Celery results from Django?
Doing

```
cel = celery.status.tasks.get(None)  
cel = status.tasks.all()
```

does not work, resulting in the aforementioned AttributeError. (`status` is the name of my app)

EDIT: I am sure tasks are saved, as [this small tutorial](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#calling-our-task) says:
*By default django-celery stores this state in the Django database. You may consider choosing an alternate result backend or disabling states alltogether (see Result Backends).*
Following the links there are only references on how to setup the DB connection and not how to retrieve the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from djcelery.models import TaskMeta

TaskMeta.objects.all()
```