# Get Celery task name from inside Django

Tags: django, celery, djcelery

I have a Django 1.5.1 webapp using Celery 3.0.23 with RabbitMQ 3.1.5.
When [reading the TaskMeta informations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098192/getting-latest-tasks-from-celery-and-display-them-using-django) from my backend using

```
from djcelery.models import TaskMeta
TaskMeta.objects.all()
```

I cannot read the task name (it is usually the method name). It is not stored in the database. Is there a way to store also the task name or to retrieve it at runtime?

If not, I am already thinking about storing it in the meta properties, but this implies that I manually have to call `update_state` on every task I create. This looks a bit clumsy to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your task name, by looking into `name` property of a task, for example:

```
In [1]: from celery import task

In [2]: @task
   ...: def hello():
   ...:     print hello.name
   ...:     

In [3]: hello()
default.hello

In [4]: hello.name
Out[4]: 'default.hello'
```

If you wish, you can call that task by name with [celery.execute.send_task()](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-call-a-task-by-name).

**UPD.** When you are using RabbitMQ as broker, Celery use `celeryev` exchange to publish all status updates for tasks. Django will not have any information about tasks, because storing all this information is a huge performance hit. You can connect to `celeryev` exchange with command:

```
python manage.py celery events
```

Or you can [flower](https://github.com/mher/flower) for same task. Both of them will show you tasks in **realtime**(not history). You can try to use [SQL-database as broker](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#database-backend-settings), way be this will help you.

Comment: I want to get the name of all tasks already executed that I fetch from the Database, not from the tasks file. I have to display them using Django.

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna, do I understand you correctly: you want to see task execution history? or you want to list all avaliable tasks?

Comment: I want to read task execution history and display all executed tasks with their name