# How do I override the backend for celery tasks

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

we're using Redis as our result backend. However for one task we'd like to override this to use RabbitMQ instead.

The documentation for [Task.backend](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.backend) says:

> The result store backend to use for this task. Defaults to the
>   CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND setting

So I had assumed that we could set `Task.backend` to a string of the same format accepted by `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND`.

So I try this:

`celeryconfig.py`

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://redis-host:7777"
```

`tasks.py`

```
@app.task(backend='amqp://guest@localhost/tasks-stg')
def my_task(params):
    ...
```

However the worker fails with :

```
[2015-05-07 13:33:49,264: ERROR/Worker-1] Process Worker-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project/python2.7_x64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/process.py", line 292, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/project/python2.7_x64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 286, in run
    self.after_fork()
  File "/project/python2.7_x64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 389, in after_fork
    self.initializer(*self.initargs)
  File "/project/python2.7_x64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/concurrency/prefork.py", line 81, in process_initializer
    app=app)
  File "/project/python2.7_x64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 178, in build_tracer
    store_result = backend.store_result
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'store_result'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation is incorrect. `Task.backend` is actually an instance of a backend class from `celery.backends`. In this case to override the task class I had to do this:

```
from celery.backends.amqp import AMQPBackend

@app.task(backend=AMQPBackend(app, url='amqp://guest@localhost/tasks-stg'))
def my_task(params):
    ...
```

However the workers continue to use the default class and don't seem to offer a way to override this.

Comment: This did work for me, despite the answered's closing remark.

Answer (score 2):

Extend & update the original accepted answer, those who hit similar issue might be interested with [List of Options available in Celery task decorator](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#list-of-options) . See [Task.backend](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#Task.backend) section :

> The result store backend to use for this task. An **instance** of one of the backend classes in `celery.backends`. Defaults to `app.backend`

Also, [AMQP result backend has been removed](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/whatsnew-5.0.html#amqp-result-backend)  since the version 5.0 , instead you could use `celery.backends.rpc.RPCBackend` .

For example :

```py
from celery.backends.rpc import RPCBackend as CeleryRpcBackend
_rpc_backend = CeleryRpcBackend(app=your_celery_app, \
        exchange=RPC_REPLY_EXCHANGE_DEFAULT_NAME, \
        exchange_type=RPC_EXCHANGE_DEFAULT_TYPE )

@your_celery_app.task(backend=_rpc_backend, ... OTHER_ARGS ... )
def your_task_function(**kwargs):
    DO_SOMETHING ...
```