# Celery proof existance of tasks

Tags: python, task, celery, status

I have the problem, that Celery assings "Pending" status to a task for tasks that are in the queue as well as non-existing ones: See
[Celery documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#pending)

I tried to solve it with a solution mentioned here: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824172/find-out-whether-celery-task-exists) 
but this did not work out for me.

I have the following setup:

- Celery 4.1.0
- Redis 4.0.9
- Python 3
- falcon 1.4.1

My tasks are defined the following `tasks.py`:

```
import celery
from celery.signals import after_task_publish

CELERY_BROKER = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

app = celery.Celery('my_app', broker=CELERY_BROKER, backend=CELERY_BACKEND)

@app.task(bind=True, name='testing_async')
def testing_async(self):
    string_result = "This is a async task call"
    return dict(status_code=1, error_message=string_result)

@after_task_publish.connect
def update_sent_state(sender=None, body=None, **kwargs):
    task = app.tasks.get(sender)
    backend = task.backend if task else app.backend
    backend.store_result(body['id'], None, "SENT")
```

Then in my `views.py` I call it:

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from app.tasks import testing_async

class TestAsync(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        task = testing_async.apply_async()
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        resp.body = json.dumps(dict(status=task.state, jobid=task.id))

class CheckIdentifierStatus(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp, task_id):
        task_result = AsyncResult(task_id)
        response = {
            'status': task_result.status,
            'state': task_result.state
        }
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        resp.body = json.dumps(response)
```

When I run my code, my status is always "Pending", but I expected it to be "SENT".

```
{'jobid': '94894297-918d-41d9-824c-591a6b5ea245', 'status': 'PENDING'}
{'status': 'PENDING', 'state': 'PENDING'}
{'status': 'SUCCESS', 'state': 'SUCCESS'}
```

Maybe someone has a hint, where I am wrong here, that I do not see the status change here.

EDIT 1:

This issue is now in planned in the celery 5.0.0 release as of their [GitHub](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3596)